# Unable to build Tezos from source - alphanet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows

I am installing Tezos on a Windows 10 Linux Subsystem (Ubuntu 18.04) following the [official Tezos instructions](http://tezos.gitlab.io/master/introduction/howtoget.html). Everything works correctly until the command `make build-deps` which produces the following error output:

```
: not foundnstall_build_deps.sh: 2: ./scripts/install_build_deps.sh:  
: not foundnstall_build_deps.sh: 5: ./scripts/install_build_deps.sh:  
/version.shnstall_build_deps.sh: 6: .: Can't open /mnt/d/development/blockchain/tezos/source/Tezos_original/tezos/scripts/
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'build-deps' failed
make: *** [build-deps] Error 2#
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue. I was using files which were on the Windows file system (/mnt/d) as from my understanding, files created on the Windows file system can also be used by the Linux Subsystem.

It looks like some of the Linux Ubuntu tools do not like using these shared files.

I am now cloning the Tezos repo straight into the Linux file system.

Comment: You can accept your own answer after 24h - glad you fixed it